# When running koverReport task, it output nothing although I have unit tests

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, kover

I try to use `kover` plugin to check test coverage of my kotlin native project.

But when I run `koverReport`, below is the log from intellij and nothings generated.

```
...

> Task :koverHtmlReport SKIPPED
> Task :koverXmlReport SKIPPED
> Task :koverReport UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 322ms
6:30:48 pm: Execution finished 'koverReport'.
```

Below was my `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.6.1"
}

...

kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    nativeTarget.apply {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting

        nativeMain.dependsOn(commonMain)
    }
}
```

Expecting code report is generated but under `build/reports`, no `kover` directory is found.

Answer (score 0):

Kover [doesn't support Kotlin/Native](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover#features), at least for now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I previously thought that `Kotlin Multiplatform` projects included `Kotlin Native`.

Actually my tests are in the `commonTest` instead of `nativeTest` from the above `build.gradle.kts`and I think I am following the structure of kotlin multiplatform project.

What is the difference between my project and a kotlin multiplatform project that is supported by Kover?

Comment: I confess I've never actually used Kover, but I imagine it's just that it hooks onto the JVM-specific Gradle tasks. It may be as simple as adding a JVM target and implementing any `expect` declarations.